# Why doesn't this fadeOut() work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fadeout

[Tested](http://jsfiddle.net/B7ndq/4/) on IE7, IE8, IE9... and the `fadeOut()` is not applied :

```
<table>
    <tr class="sideOn hidden">
        <td class="trackBotton">
            <input type="submit" value="Remove" onClick="remSide(this);return false" />
        </td>        
    </tr>
</table>

function remSide(param) {
    $(param).parents('.sideOn').fadeOut(500, function() {
           $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

Why is this and how can I fix this problem?

Also removing the `remove()` doesn't work:

```
function remSide(param) {
    $(param).parents('.sideOn').fadeOut(500);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

JQuery uses filters to do the fading in Internet Explorer, and filters only apply to elements that has layout.

You can give the table row layout like this:

```
.sideOn { position: absolute; }
```

Then the elements fade in Internet Explorer, but changing the `position` style of a table row is not recommended, so you should use some other element for what you want to fade.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: I don't have put any downvote man :) Yeah, you solution looks nice, but I'll get rid about put position_absolute on table... any other idea? Tried with zoom:1 but nothing...

Comment: Not sure why there was a downvote, this was enlightening for me at least.

Comment: @Guffa : which other elements do you suggest for example?

Comment: @markzzz: An element having layout basically means that it has a specified width and height. There is a paragraph about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @markzzz: Specifying `width` and `height` for a table row only works as `min-width` and `min-height`, it doesn't give it fixed values. Setting `position: absolute` is pretty much the only way to guarantee that a table row has layout. A `div` works without problems: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/KCbBX/

Answer (score 1):

Guffa had it right with his answer - so I'd like to offer an alternative (workaround for IE, that is):

```
function remSide(param) {
    $(param).parents('.sideOn').find('td').fadeOut(500, function() {
           $(this).parent().remove();
    });
}
```

This fades out all the `<td>`s, then removes the `<tr>` itself. Seems to work fine in IE8.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/B7ndq/3/

Comment: I haven't installed it yet, so It's sad to hear that we're still working around this stuff in IE9... I couldn't get the usual `hasLayout` triggers to work consistently with the `<tr>` and not ruin the layout...